# Sending a 403 status with every request using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, http-status-code-403

In addition to noindex and other headers, I want to send 403 status with every request on a dev server we use. I have put an .htaccess file in the home dir (above the web root) so that every request is tagged, and all seems to be working well, minus the 200 OK status.

Is there a way that .htaccess can set status as 403 to all requests without actually triggering the forbidden page mechanisms? This would work similar to how php can do it with `header('HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden');`. I don't wanna have to worry about putting `header()` style fixes all over the stuff below in the folders....would be far easier and more consistant via .htaccess (with ability to tag assets to boot).

Comment: `Is there a way that .htaccess can set status as 403 to all requests without actually triggering the forbidden page mechanisms` - What do you mean by that?

Comment: Everything in and below web root should still render as-is, but send a 403 status instead of sending a status of 200 OK. Pages, assets, folders, whatever - should all work fine, but will still be viewed as "Forbidden" to automation that cares about that sort of thing. Basically, I need an equivalent to using PHP's `header('HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden');` but on a mass scale in top level htaccess instead. Not sure it's possible to do this. Hope that makes sense :)